# mysql errno: 150 “Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed”- MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, foreign-key-relationship, mysql-error-1005

**MESSAGE_MAP TABLE**

```
    CREATE TABLE `message_map` (
      `message_from` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `message_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `message_to` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `message_status` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
  ALTER TABLE `message_map`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`message_from`,`message_id`,`message_to`),
  ADD KEY `FK_ij6tystusydqijqp8lgoigo1c` (`message_id`),
```

**USER TABLE**

```
 CREATE TABLE `user` (
      `USER_ID` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `PASSWORD` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `PHONE_NUMBER` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `USER_NAME` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
   ALTER TABLE `user`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `USER_ID_UNIQUE` (`USER_ID`);
```

> I tried below query to apply Foreign Key Constraint

```
ALTER TABLE `demo`.`message_map` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_MSG_MAP_USER`
  FOREIGN KEY (`message_from`)
  REFERENCES `demo`.`user` (`USER_ID`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_MSG_MAP_USER_TO`
  FOREIGN KEY (`message_to`)
  REFERENCES `demo`.`user` (`USER_ID`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**Im getting the following error**

> ERROR 1005: Can't create table `<shema>`.`#sql-1964_4` (errno: 150 >"Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

**My Observation**

> The data type of the columns (message_from,message_to) and USER_ID are
>   the same. And also USER_ID is a primary key.

**Question is**

What went wrong?

Thank you for the answers

Comment: 3 columns primary key?

Comment: Your posted code contains error.

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key.  Get rid of the latter; it is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

First there are a number of errors in your code that makes it a bit cumbersome to test. Second, make sure you use the same charset in both tables, I changed message_map to utf8:

```
DROP TABLE message_map;
CREATE TABLE message_map (
  message_from varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  message_id varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  message_to varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  message_status bit(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE message_map
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (message_from,message_id,message_to),
    ADD KEY FK_ij6tystusydqijqp8lgoigo1c (message_id);

ALTER TABLE message_map 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MSG_MAP_USER
    FOREIGN KEY (message_from)
        REFERENCES user (USER_ID)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MSG_MAP_USER_TO
    FOREIGN KEY (message_to)
        REFERENCES user (USER_ID)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I removed demo from the foreign key definition.