# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `carparkful`.`#sql-3b64_3` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE user
(userid INT(10), uname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, phone_num VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, car_plate VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (userid));

INSERT INTO user (userid, uname, phone_num, car_plate)
VALUES (576, 'alvin', '81005199', 'sgu1256t'), (877, 'dominic', '97972841', 'sga8814e'), (112, 'desmond', '97551488', 'slj8422y');

CREATE TABLE carpark
(carparkid INT (10), location VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (carparkid));

INSERT INTO carpark (carparkid, location)
VALUES ('001', '25 toa payoh lorong 8'), ('002', '45 burghley drive'), ('003', 'ang mo kio hub');

CREATE TABLE lot
(carparkid INT(10) NOT NULL, lot_num INT(3) NOT NULL, lot_status ENUM('empty', 'reserved', 'occupied') DEFAULT 'empty');

INSERT INTO lot (carparkid, lot_num)
VALUES(001, 001), (001, 002), (001, 003), (001, 004), (001, 005), (002, 001), (002, 002), (002, 003), (002, 004), (002, 005), (003, 001), (003, 002), (003, 003), (003, 004), (003, 005);
```

Here are mine codes so far, but i need to alter carparkid in table lot foreign key to carpark. When i use this code:

```
ALTER TABLE lot
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_carparklot
FOREIGN KEY (carparkid) REFERENCES carpark(carparkid)
```

it works fine, but when i use this:

```
ALTER TABLE lot
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_carparklot
FOREIGN KEY (carparkid) REFERENCES carpark(carparkid)
ON DELETE CASCADE            
ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT;
```

it gives me the error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `carparkful`.`#sql-3b64_3` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Comment: So the error specifically is on the `on update set default`. The `on delete cascade works` as does `on update cascade`  So the error has specifically to do with the `set default` for the `on update`

Comment: InnoDB or NDB?  According to  [DOCS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html): SET DEFAULT: This action is recognized by the MySQL parser, ***but both InnoDB and NDB reject table definitions containing ON DELETE SET DEFAULT or ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT clauses***  This implies `On Update set default` is not supported.

Comment: nope both cascade and default have error

Comment: I have to disagree: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04a02/1/0  seems to work fine.  but it uses the `on delete cascade` and `on update cascade`  What engine?

Comment: yup its works for cascade, i drop the foreign key and tried again. whats the issue with on update set default

Comment: Couldn't say other than docs simply say it's not a supported feature.  You may get more detail if you use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` about the error.  that hint sourced form this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361838/mysql-errno-150-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-mariadb

Comment: btw its innodb engine

Comment: This is a duplicate of question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943459/innodb-mysql-unable-to-set-on-delete-set-default-how-to-set which is also unanswered.  and this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74627/difference-between-on-delete-cascade-on-update-cascade-in-mysql basically says mySQL simply hasn't implemented it yet.

Comment: You may want to look at peterm's answer  (unaccepted) in the aforementioned duplicate question link.

Answer (score 0):

Operating as designed/documented for InnoDB and NDB engines.

According to [DOCS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html): SET DEFAULT: This action is recognized by the MySQL parser, but ***both InnoDB and NDB reject table definitions containing*** `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` or `ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT` clauses

This implies On Update `set default` option/parameter is not supported